# Selenium Explicit Waits

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to automate a sharepoint-based application, which can be slow at times. In the example below, I am trying to wrap the password input into an explicit wait. Currently, Selenium runs the test to fast and it results in failure to perform the actions.

How can I wrap the password portion into a selenium explicit way?

```
    // Enter username
        var input_Username = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("username_input"));
        input_Username.SendKeys("admin");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3000));


        // Enter pasword

        var input_Password = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("pw_input"));
        input_Password.SendKeys("password");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track.

`WebDriverWait` instance has been created, now you just need to call it like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3000));

var input_Password = wait.Until(d=> d.FindElement(By.Id("pw_input")));
input_Password.SendKeys("password");
```

Please refer to C# API [doc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) for more details. Relevant classes are under `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI` Namespace, in which there is an `ExpectedConditions` class that would be handy.

```
var input_Password = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("pw_input")));
```

Also note that your code sets the timeout to 3000 seconds, seems way too long.